# What anime features a guy who transforms into a green monster like creature?

Tags: story-identification, anime

First, the guy accidentally gets wounded and a strange thing gets implanted in his arm. The thing causes his arm to swell but he visits a doctor who tries to keep it in check by bandaging him and giving some medication to him. But, one fine day it gets out of control and the thing takes over his body leading to his transformation.

I described a clipping I saw a long time ago probably on Facebook. Can anyone recall an anime like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly "Xam'd: Lost Memories"? (2008) It matches on a character getting an object (a gem) lodged in his arm which causes it to swell and deform. The main female character wraps it and uses the magical technology of the series to keep it from transforming him entirely, but of course he ends up turning several times into a monster - it's primarily white and orange, with only small patches of green, however.